# UIPickerView setter in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to write a setter method for UIPickerView which will be created from my IBOutLet. In Objective C it was pretty straight forward but in Swift it has changed a bit. The setter method never gets executed.

My Current implementation in swift:

```
class PickerController: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var _pickerView: UIPickerView! {

    get {
        return self._pickerView
    }
    set {
        self.pickerView = _pickerView
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

But if I do in Objective C following method can be declared on the outlet.

```
- (void)setPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
   _pickerView = pickerView;
   _pickerView.delegate = self;
   _pickerView.dataSource = self;
   [_pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

How can I achieve the setter method in Swift ?

Comment: in set block use `newValue` instead if `_pickerView `

Comment: set block never gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var pickerView: UIPickerView! {
    didSet {
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives my exc_bad_access...at         self.pickerView = newValue...
do you think I am releasing it ? but its an outlet attached to storyboard...

Comment: Remove @IBOutlet if you need to set pickerView object programmatically why you defined it as an IBOutlet ?

Comment: ok I think I got the issue fixed...but even after setting the delegate the pickerview is not shown...also the delegate methods are not called...

Comment: You need to add pickerView to view. This is not the pickerView that you defined in your XIB or StoryBoard